# Website Background Image Horizontal Animation Infinate Loop?

Tags: jquery, css, html, background

I want to put a picture/s of cloud images like vector of clouds that will slowly, but infinitely animate form left to right, or right to left, on my website background. I'm not not good with coding but I thought a jQuery plugin should do the trick. I already have a gradient background with CSS so I'd just like to put some white clouds to animate between the bg and content of the site. Sorry if this is a very "Duh" question! Or maybe HTML5?

Comment: You might consider an animated gif of clouds moving (if you can find one or create one).  It's simpler and works in all browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter background position using jquery and intervals:

http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/animated-background-image-with-jquery

*The demo gives a 404 page, but download the ZIP file and you are good to go, and remember to change the repeat background setting from `repeat-y` to `repeat-x`. Depends on what you want.

PS. They use clouds in the downloadable example! ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it to work, I didn't see your last answer!

Comment: Glad I could help... it's very simple and easy to use example. Cheerz buddy

Answer (score 3):

You can do with pure CSS animation:

HTML:

```
<div id="cloud"> -picture of a cloud- </div>
```

CSS:

```
  @-webkit-keyframes move {
    0%   { left: 0px; }
    50%  { left: 1000px; }
    100% { left: 0px; }
  }
  @-moz-keyframes move {
    0%   { left: 0px; }
    50%  { left: 1000px; }
    100% { left: 0px; }
  }
  @-ms-keyframes move {
    0%   { left: 0px; }
    50%  { left: 1000px; }
    100% { left: 0px; }
  }
  @-o-keyframes move {
    0%   { left: 0px; }
    50%  { left: 1000px; }
    100% { left: 0px; }
  }
  @keyframes move {
    0%   { left: 0px; }
    50%  { left: 1000px; }
    100% { left: 0px; }
  }

  #cloud {
    -webkit-animation: move 100s infinite;
    -moz-animation: move 100s infinite;
    -ms-animation: move 100s infinite;
    -o-animation: move 100s infinite;
    animation: move 100s infinite;
  }
```

Comment: and is the 100s in #cloud {} the speed control?

Comment: Well, in general yes, although you should add your own code for the cloud image and it's properties, like width, height, etc.

Comment: 100s is the time of the animation, you can see that at 0% (second 0) the cloud is at point 0, at 50% (second 50) the cloud is at 1000px, and at 100% (second 100) the cloud is at point 0 again.
Repeats infinite.

Comment: Ah okay thanks! should be okay if i just make it the right size picture as png though?

Comment: <div id="cloud"> url(../images/cloud.png); </div>

<style type="text/css">

  @-webkit-keyframes move {
    0%   { left: 0px; }
    50%  { left: 1000px; }
    100% { left: 0px; }
  }
  @-moz-keyframes move {
    0%   { left: 0px; }
    50%  { left: 1000px; }
    100% { left: 0px; }
  }

  #cloud {
    -webkit-animation: move 100s infinite;
    -moz-animation: move 100s infinite;
  }

</style>

Comment: does that look good? and do some of those go into html? im using joomla 1.5 on a template i got

Comment: I'm confused! Am I putting this in the template.css? or index.php as html? and is <div id="cloud"> url(../images/cloud.png); </div>  correct coding?

Comment: I don't really know "Joomla", but this code should work. Note the -webkit and -moz (there's also -ms) for different browsers.

Comment: the code for html file: <div id="cloud> ... </div>. and for the css file all the rest but without the "<style..></style>"

Comment: thanks keeper would the<div id="cloud> be <div id="cloud">? with the " after cloud

Comment: and how would i link the picture if its is in images folder? is it <img scr="../images/cloud.png">? thanks! index html is in theme folder and cloud.png is in theme/image

Comment: You can link the picture through html: <img scr="..."> or with css: #cloud {background-image:url("..."); }

Comment: i have a feeling the @-webkit- isnt supported or something it is grayed out till the {

Comment: was the same for @fontface :C

Comment: Supported browsers in this example are Gecko (Firefox) and Webkit (Chrome, Safari). It should, however be updated to include support for Internet Explorer, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772747(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should consider this question and the answer markup to help you:

- [continuous loop with divs and jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754237/continuous-loop-with-divs-and-jquery)