# Moving background image in a loop from top to down

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

I need to change this javascript, it should moving from top do down!

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var x = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
            x-=1;
            $('body').css('background-position', x + 'px 0');
        }, 10);
    })
</script>

body {
    background-image: url('img/bg-body.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Thank you guys!
P.S.: Here is the link where I find it:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279311/website-background-image-horizontal-animation-infinate-loop)

Answer (score 1):

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/7fa0jjzq/show

Code:

```
$(function(){
        var x = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
            $('body').css('background-position','0'+--x + 'px');
        }, 10);
})
```

**Explanation:**

change css `repeat-y', and change in jquery x to 0, as don't want to animate y, and change x to x variable.

Answer (score 0):

change `x + 'px 0'` to `'0 ' + x + 'px'`

when working with css properties that specify xy positioning, the first number is always on the horizontal ruler (x) and the second one on the vertical ruler (y)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple. What sets the position? You'll notice that x get's decremented with every loop. To make it go the other way, just increment it:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var x = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        x+=1;
        $('body').css('background-position', x + 'px 0');
    }, 10);
})
</script>
```